# Obtain the shortest distance between two points on a sphere

Tags: geometry, geodesy

Let person  A be at  latitude : 40N and longitude 0.4W

Let person B be a the latitude: 40N and longitude 74E

Find the shortest distance between them.

We use Haversine formula:

$$a = \sin^2(\Delta\phi/2) + \cos \phi_1 \cdot \cos \phi_2 \cdot \sin^2(\Delta\Lambda/2)$$

Phi=latitude, Lambda=Longitude.

Convert to radians:
Person A:  $\phi=40\cdot \frac{\pi}{180}=0.7$, $\lambda=0.4\cdot \frac{\pi}{180}=0.007$

Person B: $\phi=40\cdot \frac{\pi}{180}=0.7$,  $\lambda=74\cdot \frac{\pi}{180}=1.3$

$\Delta\phi=1.3-0.007=1.293$, $\Delta\lambda=0$

$$a =  \cos0.7 \cdot \cos0.7 \cdot sin^2(0.6465)=0.212$$

Then we find

$c = 2 \cdot \arctan(2( \sqrt{a}, \sqrt{(1−a)} )$

We insert for $a$:

$c = 2 \cdot \arctan(2( \sqrt{0.212}, \sqrt{(1−0.212)} )=(1.48845, 2.11566)$

Then we calculate the distance, with the Earth radius at $R=6371km$

$d = 6371 \cdot c$

But how does that distant result when $c$ is a coordinate?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $c$ is a scalar.

Comment: Sorry, I see a coordinate. How do you get a scalar? The norm that coordinate, $\sqrt{1.488^2+2.11^2}$=2.5?

Comment: Your coordinates are the latitude and longitude: $\phi$ and $\Lambda$. Using them in the formula for $a$ yields a scalar, which also means that $c$ is a scalar.

Comment: use the standard formula for the angular distance in radians along the great circle that connects the two points as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance , multiply by the radius  of the sphere and that is the distance.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your confusion is a semantical misunderstanding about the formula $\arctan(x, y)$.

The formula $\arctan(x, y)$ **has 2 inputs**, $x$ and $y$, and **has 1 output**, $\theta$.

$\theta$ corresponds to the angle formed by the right triangle in which $a$ is opposite to the angle, and $b$ is adjacent to the angle.

In conclusion, you performed element-wise calculation on a vector, when instead you should have computed $\arctan$ like I explained above.

[image: Right Triangle]

Comment: So the exact calculation of $\arctan(1.48845, 2.11566)$ is  $\arctan(2.11566/1.48845)$?

Comment: Not quite; $\arctan(1.48845,2.11566)=\arctan(1.48845/2.11566)$

Comment: that is bizarre, Mathematica says I wrote it right. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arctan%28a%2Cb%29

Comment: Mathematica has a very special notation for the two arguments of
the arctan2, which differs from the notation used everywhere else. Mathematical libraries of programming languages (C/C++, Java, Fortran, python) and
other CAS systems like Maple write arctan2(y,x) where Mma writes arctan(x,y
). In summary: do not use Mma notation if you can avoid it but stick to the
 notation that 99 percent of the available packes convene to.

Answer (score 1):

The angular distance as observed from the Earth center is
according to the standard formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance
$$
\arccos( \sin 40^\circ\sin 40^\circ + \cos 40^\circ \cos 40^\circ\cos 74.4^\circ)
=
\arccos( 0.41317+ 0.5868\times 0.2689)
$$
$$
=
0.96309 rad
$$
so the distance is $6371\times 0.96309$ km $\approx 6135.8$ km.